# Reading file using shell script, format of the line has changed

Tags: linux, bash

I am reading a file using the following code:

```
displayLine(){
    echo $line
}

filename="SampleFile"
while read line
do
    displayLine $line
done < "$filename"
```

The format of the file that I am getting after using the script is this:

```
ID EVENT OK NOK
101 ABC1123 ok nok
101 ABC1223 ok      
101 ABC1323 ok nok
101 ABC1423 ok nok
```

But the actual format of the file is like this:

```
ID  EVENT       OK      NOK
101 ABC1123     ok      nok
101 ABC1223     ok      
101 ABC1323     ok      nok
101 ABC1423     ok      nok
```

My script is somehow trimming the extra spaces between the words. However, I want the actual format of the file.

Could anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Thanks!!

Comment: How are you viewing the file? What does it look like if you `cat` it?

Comment: @dan08 It looks exactly like the actual file. I have viewed the file using both vi editor and cat command. They show the file with correct format. However, when I use the aforementioned script, it removes the extra spaces between the words.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thank!! It works

Comment: Sidenote: Read up about functions, you're abusing them.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yeah sure, I am new to shell scripting. I am just having some hands on calling functions with parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a console window:

```
echo    101 ABC1123     ok      nok
```

What do you get?

Now try

```
echo "101 ABC1123     ok      nok"
```

Now, try echo "$line" in your script.